# Unsure of the way"&&" conditional works in Java

Tags: java, loops, conditional-statements

I'm having some basic trouble with my condition and I have no idea why.

What I want is to run this loop while `e1` and `e2` and `e3` are bigger than `tol` but it only takes into account the `e3>tol` condition, and ignores the two before it.

this is the code:

```
do{

   ....

   }while((e1>tol)&&(e2>tol)&&(e3>tol));
```

I believe it has something to do with the && or that I'm comparing them to the same variable `tol` but I'm still not sure why.

I managed it to make it work with three nested ifs:

```
do{

    .....

          if(e1<tol)
            if(e2<tol)
                if(e3<tol)
                    b=true;

    }while(b==false);
```

but that's not the way I need it.

Thanks for your time.

This is the full code:

```
public class GaussSeidel {


public static void op(double tol){

    double e1=0,e2=0,e3=0;
    double fx1,fx2,fx3;
    double x1=0,x2=0,x3=0;
    int n=0;


    do{
        n++;
        System.out.println(n+".- x1= "+x1+"/x2= "+x2+"/x3= "+x3+
                "/E1= "+e1+"/E2= "+e2+"/E3= "+e3+"\n");

        fx1=((27-x2-x3)/-2);
        e1=Math.abs((fx1-x1)/fx1);
        x1=fx1;
        fx2=((85+2*x1-x3)/4);
        e2=Math.abs((fx2-x2)/fx2);
        x2=fx2;
        fx3=((109-x1+3*x2)/6);
        e3=Math.abs((fx3-x3)/fx3);
        x3=fx3;

    }while((e1>tol)&&(e2>tol)&&(e3>tol));

    System.out.println(n+".- x1= "+x1+"/x2= "+x2+"/x3= "+x3+
            "/E1= "+e1+"/E2= "+e2+"/E3= "+e3+"\n");


}

public static void main (String[]args){
    op(Double.parseDouble
            (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Tolerance")));
}
```

}

If I delete the other two conditionals and only use `}while(e1>tol);` it works and the same goes for the other two, if I condition them alone, it works, my problem is while trying to check that the three of them meet the condition.

Comment: Please show enough code to reproduce the problem. As written, I see nothing wrong with your initial loop. Additionally, please provide some justification for why you believe `it only takes into account the e3>tol condition`.

Comment: Also of note: the opposite of `>` is `<=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` statements:

```
if (e1 < tol)
    if (e2 < tol)
        if (e3 < tol)
            b = true;
```

Is the same as:

```
b = (e1 < tol && e2 < tol && e3 < tol);
```

I.e. it is true only when *all* are true.

Your `while` loop condition `(b == false)` (better written as `(! b)`), is of course the opposite. When reversing a boolean condition like that, you reverse *everything*, in your case `&&` ⟺ `||`, and `<` ⟺ `>=`, so you get:

```
} while (e1 >= tol || e2 >= tol || e3 >= tol);
```

As you can see, your initial error was that you needed to use `||` (or), not `&&` (and).

Whether the `=` should be there, or you meant `(e1 > tol || e2 > tol || e3 > tol)`, is for you to decide.

In plain English, the `while (! b)` reads as "while not B", or "stop when B", and since B was defined as "true if all of E1, E2, and E3 are less than TOL", combined it meant "stop when all of E1, E2, and E3 are less than TOL".

With the updated `while` condition, that reads as "continue while at least one of E1, E2, or E3 are greater than (or equal to) TOL".

Comment: Thanks a lot Andreas, I thought that if I used  `||` it would be that it needed to meet only one of the three conditions but turns out it was the oposite. Note taken on the `(!b)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not exactly the same, in the while containing the '&&' you are expecting all three e* to be greater than tol on each iteration while on the second snippet you are not doing exactly the same, e1 and e2 may besmaller than tol while not e3, which wouldn't happen on the first snippet.
HTH

Answer (score 0):

Try writing a unit test and debug the condition when it would be true and enter the loop. You could stagger your code like this to debug each line:

```
do{

   ....

   }while((e1>tol)
           &&(e2>tol)
            &&(e3>tol));
```